# Getting average value by month for certain months in R

Tags: r, date

I have data like this

```
      logMosqm2  Date
[1,] -4.0000000 10296
[2,] -4.0000000 10313
[3,] -4.0000000 10342
[4,] -4.0000000 10388
[5,] -0.9592633 10526
[6,] -4.0000000 10572
```

only with four more columns (similar to the first) and many more rows.

I would like to get the average by month for logMosm2 (and the other similar variables) but only for months that are in the the years 2004, 2005 and 2006.

Regarding the dates: these came from

```
yearfish <- cbind(logMosqm2, Date)
```

but just using Date gives

```
"1998-03-11" "1998-03-28" "1998-04-26" "1998-06-11" "1998-10-27"
```

The dates in the table are days since Jan 1, 1970.

EDIT: I found the `yearmon` function in the `ZOO` package. So I now have a variable yearmon:

```
[1] "Mar 1998" "Mar 1998" "Apr 1998" "Jun 1998"
 [5] "Oct 1998" "Dec 1998" "Apr 1999" "Nov 1999"
 [9] "Feb 2000" "Feb 2000" "Mar 2000" "Apr 2000"
[13] "May 2000" "Jun 2000" "Oct 2000" "Dec 2000"
[17] "Mar 2001" "Jun 2001" "Sep 2001" "Jan 2002"
[21] "Jun 2002" "Dec 2002" "Apr 2003" "Jun 2003"
[25] "Jan 2004" "Mar 2004" "Apr 2004" "May 2004"
[29] "Jun 2004" "Jun 2004" "Jul 2004" "Jul 2004"
[33] "Jul 2004" "Aug 2004" "Aug 2004" "Aug 2004"
[37] "Aug 2004" "Aug 2004" "Aug 2004" "Sep 2004"
[41] "Sep 2004" "Sep 2004" "Sep 2004" "Sep 2004"
[45] "Sep 2004" "Sep 2004" "Sep 2004" "May 2005"
[49] "May 2005" "May 2005" "May 2005" "May 2005"
[53] "May 2005" "Jun 2005" "Jun 2005" "Jun 2005"
[57] "Jul 2005" "Jul 2005" "Jul 2005" "Aug 2005"
[61] "Aug 2005" "Aug 2005" "Sep 2005" "Sep 2005"
[65] "Sep 2005" "May 2006" "May 2006" "May 2006"
[69] "Jun 2006" "Jun 2006" "Jun 2006" "Jul 2006"
[73] "Jul 2006" "Sep 2006" "Sep 2006" "Apr 2007"
[77] "May 2007" "Jul 2007" "Sep 2007" "Jan 2008"
[81] "Mar 2008" "May 2008"
```

Comment: What is that date format?

Comment: The data originally come from a .csv file where date was formatted 10/14/1993. I read them in to `R` with read.csv. These are (I presume) unformatted dates.

Comment: I am still confused. So `10296` above is `10/2/96`?

Comment: You are going to have to go back to year and month to do the averages, so maybe just split `Date` into a `Year` and `Month` field and do the mean with those fields.

Comment: If you wanted the summaries by year-month then you should have said so. Saying "by month" means all the January values get `mean`-ed together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the test dataset `camm.recent` defined at the end we create a grouping variable `g` which consists originally of sequence numbers.  For any duplicated `yearmon` between 2004 and 2006 inclusive we replace the sequence number with the sequence number of the prior first occurence of that `yearmon` by filling in the duplicates with `NA` and using `na.locf`.  Then use `aggregate` to compute the means.

```
# this uses the test data set defined at the end
library(zoo)

# create an appropriate grouping variable, g
ym <- camm.recent$yearmon
between <- ym >= "Jan 2004" & ym <= "Dec 2006"
g <- replace(seq_along(ym), duplicated(ym) & between, NA)
g <- na.locf(g)

# aggregate by g
aggregate(camm.recent, data.frame(g), mean)[-1] # -1 removes g from output
```

Here is the code to create the test data set:

```
library(zoo)
ym <- c("Mar 1998", "Mar 1998", "Apr 1998", "Jun 1998",
"Oct 1998", "Dec 1998", "Apr 1999", "Nov 1999",
"Feb 2000", "Feb 2000", "Mar 2000", "Apr 2000",
"May 2000", "Jun 2000", "Oct 2000", "Dec 2000",
"Mar 2001", "Jun 2001", "Sep 2001", "Jan 2002",
"Jun 2002", "Dec 2002", "Apr 2003", "Jun 2003",
"Jan 2004", "Mar 2004", "Apr 2004", "May 2004",
"Jun 2004", "Jun 2004", "Jul 2004", "Jul 2004",
"Jul 2004", "Aug 2004", "Aug 2004", "Aug 2004",
"Aug 2004", "Aug 2004", "Aug 2004", "Sep 2004",
"Sep 2004", "Sep 2004", "Sep 2004", "Sep 2004",
"Sep 2004", "Sep 2004", "Sep 2004", "May 2005",
"May 2005", "May 2005", "May 2005", "May 2005",
"May 2005", "Jun 2005", "Jun 2005", "Jun 2005",
"Jul 2005", "Jul 2005", "Jul 2005", "Aug 2005",
"Aug 2005", "Aug 2005", "Sep 2005", "Sep 2005",
"Sep 2005", "May 2006", "May 2006", "May 2006",
"Jun 2006", "Jun 2006", "Jun 2006", "Jul 2006",
"Jul 2006", "Sep 2006", "Sep 2006", "Apr 2007",
"May 2007", "Jul 2007", "Sep 2007", "Jan 2008",
"Mar 2008", "May 2008")
camm.recent <- data.frame(logMosqm2 = seq_along(ym), 
    Date = as.Date(as.yearmon(ym)),
    yearmon = as.yearmon(ym))
```

Answer (score 2):

Need a better example. All those dates are in 1998.

```
tapply(inp[ , 'logMosqm2'], format(as.Date(inp[ , 'Date'], origin=as.Date("1970-01-01") ),format="%Y" ),mean )
     1998 
-3.493211
```

It now appears that you wanted what would be delivered by changing the format to "$y-%m", so that 2003-01 is different than 2004-01. (This is not what you wrote.)

But here's how to do it once we have a sensible example to which we can apply a restriction function:

```
tapply(inp[ , 'logMosqm2'], format(as.Date(inp[ , 'Date'], origin=as.Date("1970-01-01") ),format="%m" ),mean )
        03         04         06         10         12 
-4.0000000 -4.0000000 -4.0000000 -0.9592633 -4.0000000
```

`rd.txt` was a function I created before the text argument to `scan` was added so I could do quick input from posters, such as yourself, who had not learned the virtues of posting examples with dput:

```
rd.txt <-     function (txt, header = TRUE, ...) 
{        rd <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = header, ...)
    closeAllConnections()
    rd}

inp <- data.matrix(rd.txt(" logMosqm2  Date
  -4.0000000 10296
  -4.0000000 10313
  -4.0000000 10342
  -4.0000000 10388
  -0.9592633 10526
  -4.0000000 10572") )
```

Comment: What is inp? How could I do this on a data frame? Thanks

Comment: Well, my `inp` is a matrix, since you showed an R matrix, but I think the code should have worked with a data.frame, since the indexing was by column name.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` with an example

```
#Example
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
all_dates <- as.numeric(seq(as.Date("2004/01/01"), as.Date("2008/12/31"), "day"))
dates <- sample(all_dates, 1000, replace = T)
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(1000), dates = dates)
dt
#               x dates
#   1: -0.6018928 12943
#   2: -0.9936986 13858
#   3:  1.0267851 13165
#   4:  0.7510613 14031
#   5: -1.5091665 14136

dt[, dates := as.Date(dates, origin = "1970-01-01")]
dt
#               x      dates
#   1: -0.6018928 2005-06-09
#   2: -0.9936986 2007-12-11
#   3:  1.0267851 2006-01-17
#   4:  0.7510613 2008-06-01
#   5: -1.5091665 2008-09-14

#Relevant Code  
dt[, c("month", "year") := list(month(dates), year(dates))]
dt[year %in% c(2004, 2005, 2006), mean(x), by = month]
#    month           V1
# 1:     6 -0.044292743
# 2:     1  0.078148206
# 3:     3  0.062165254
# 4:     8 -0.149267201
# 5:    10 -0.024994773
# 6:     4  0.159856357
# 7:    11 -0.028046083
# 8:     7  0.019404375
# 9:     9  0.117634410
#10:    12  0.074059451
#11:     2 -0.001347801
#12:     5  0.096914779
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate your data frame with columns for Year and Month, then subset for the years you want, and use `tapply` to get the mean by factor:

```
d = data.frame(x=1:9,y=c(2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003),
     month=rep(c('a','b','c'),3) )
ds = subset(d,y>2001)
tapply(ds$x,ds$month,mean)
```

Data look like:

```
  x    y z
1 1 2001 a
2 2 2001 b
3 3 2001 c
4 4 2002 a
5 5 2002 b
6 6 2002 c
7 7 2003 a
8 8 2003 b
9 9 2003 c
```

Output is:

```
  a   b   c 
5.5 6.5 7.5
```

Comment: Do NOT use $ indexing in the subset argument to subset. The whole point of subset is to evealuate the column names in the environment of its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.  I have solved it with your help.  Here is what I did

```
library(zoo)
camm.recent$yearmon <- as.yearmon(camm.recent$Date)

camm.recent$avglogMosqm2[camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2003" &
                           camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2007"] <-
     subset(tapply(camm.recent$logMosqm2, camm.recent$yearmon,
                   mean), camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2003" &
                     camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2007")
camm.recent$avglogMosqm2[camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2004"] <-
   camm.recent$logMosqm2[camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2004"]

camm.recent$avglogMosqm2[camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2006"] <-
  camm.recent$logMosqm2[camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2006"]

camm.recent$newdate[camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2003" &
                           camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2007"] <-
  subset(tapply(camm.recent$Date, camm.recent$yearmon,
                mean), camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2003" &
           camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2007")
camm.recent$newdate[camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2004"] <-
  camm.recent$Date[camm.recent$yearmon < "Jan 2004"]

camm.recent$newdate[camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2006"] <-
  camm.recent$Date[camm.recent$yearmon > "Dec 2006"]
```